# Solve the multiple ideal diode circuits problem

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, diodes, multiplexer, ideal

> Find the Q-points for the diodes in the four circuits in Fig. P3.68 using (a) the ideal diode model and (b) the constant voltage drop model with Von = 0.7 V. Note that Resistor = 15kOhm

The second picture is my solution, I don't know if it is right or wrong.

[image]
[image]

Comment: You have forgotten to include the ideal diodes when you converted the diodes to voltage sources. Current can't flow from left to right through D2.

Comment: Why have you used 15 k resistors in your solution (not that it matters as it happens)? Are you trying to solve a different problem?

Comment: @Transistor This means that we can assume that the Current flow right to left through D2?

Comment: @Andyaka I have edited my question, it is actually 15kOhm, can I assume that the current I2 flow is right to left through D2? and the current I3 flow is downward?

Comment: "*This means that we can assume that the Current flow right to left through D2?*" No. If the maths shows that current is flowing left to right but there is an ideal diode blocking it then the current must be 0. Think! If you removed D1 and left that branch open-circuit then how much current would flow?

Answer (score 0):

You can't solve the problem by linear analysis because it doesn't account for the diode not conducting when reverse biased. The best method is this: -

[image]